# Database design for create/revise/delete request form

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-schema

I am working on a web application that replaces paper-based forms to request creation/revision/deletion of courses, and I need help on the best database design practices for storing the requested items.

**Note**

- The database is just for requested data. Once the request is approved, the data must be manually entered into a different system. ( we have no control over this)
- Request could be revised multiple times before it gets approved, and we need the revision history of each request
- We need to track statuses for each request
- There are 30+ questions to create a course
- There are 3-30+ questions to revise a course (depends on how many items need to be revised)
- There are 5 questions to delete a course

**My Approach 1**

In this approach, I would store all data for create/revise/delete in the `RequestDetail` table. Since each `RequestDetail` can have multiple items such as `CourseMode` (e.g. online, face-to-face), there are some tables associated with each `RequestDetail`.
[image]

The table below is an example: 
When a user requested to create a course (`RequestID:1`), there are two revisions (title and fee changed) until it gets approved. But all columns for Revision and Deletion are `NULL`.

When a user requested to revise a CourseFee (`RequestID:2`), the user enters the new fee and the reason for revision, and the remaining columns for Creation and Deletion are `NULL`.

When a user requested to delete the course (`RequestID:3`), the user enters the reason for deletion, and again the remaining columns are `NULL`.

Since the purpose of this data is more like a data warehouse, could this be simple and easy to handle? But the table needs to allow Nulls for almost all fields (for creation, most of fields are required).

[image]

**My Approach 2**

In this approach, revisions of requests are handled the same way as the first approach, but create separate tables for Revisions and Deletions. But this approach seems redundant and not clean.

[image]

Personally I prefer the first approach but what the best database design practices would be in this case? Is there anything I overlooked or I need to be careful of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like a revision can change anything about a course, so if you had separate CreateRequest and ReviseRequest tables, pretty much every column would have to be duplicated. I don't see any good reason to do that.

Deletion might arguably be more debatable as most of the data is irrelevant. Still, I don't see anything gained by making a separate table for it. So what if irrelevant fields are null? So it has a bunch of nulls.

Actually I wouldn't create separate columns for "revision reason" and "delete reason". I'd just make one column and call it "request reason" or some such.

You should have some field that tells you which type of request it is. (Or is that what FormTypeID is?)

Comment: Yes, `FormTypeID` is to tell which type of request it is. And if `FormTypeID` is "Deletion" then the row will have many nulls as most of fields are irrelevant for a course deletion. It makes sense to not create separate columns for "revision reason" and "delete reason". Thank you.